# How to show group by value in Oracle SQL developer

Tags: sql, group-by, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to display group by field name after doing sum of columns in Oracle SQL Developer, but not getting.

Following is my data -

[image]

Looking for output as follow -

[image]

Here is my query  -

Select ID,Name, Sum(Amount) From Table1 Group By Name Order By SUM (Amount)DESC;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `listagg()` but eliminating duplicates is tricky, because it doesn't support `distinct`.  One method uses `row_number()` and `case`:

```
select id,
       listagg(case when seqnum = 1 then name end, ',') within group (order by name desc) as names,
       sum(amount)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by id, name order by id) as seqnum
      from table1 t
     ) t
group by id;
```

`listagg()` ignores `NULL` values.

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7c50f368cde0a09f8aaba9eef7f586a0) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: can you please explain more, i tried above query but some error there

Comment: @MagicduetoLogic . . .I added a db<>fiddle. It works fine.